# Boost.Python.ArgumentError during landmarks detection using Dlib

Tags: python-2.7, boost-python, dlib

I have a problem using `shape_predictor` for face landmarks detection using `Dlib`.

I compiled dlib and verified boost lib path according to [these issue](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/124) and [this one](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/177), but still having the same error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_landmark_detection.py", line 66, in <module>
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    shape_predictor.__init__(shape_predictor, str)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(boost::python::api::object, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(_object*)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem given two otherwise exact same Ubuntu 16 versions. 
What did the trick was compiling with g++-5.4 instead of g++-4.9.

```
sudo apt-get install g++-5
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 60
```

You might also just change the CMake-Flags I guess.

Answer (score 0):

A thing I can think of is that your predictor_path can not be converted to std::string. Can it be in Unicode? Are you using Python 3.*?

Comment: I sed the I use python 2.7 and anaconda. OpenCV 3

Comment: I replaced the predictor_path by a hardcoded string in Unicode format, but still having the same problem

Comment: My proposal a bit of opposite: try to explicitly convert your string to ascii. The proposal is based on an assumption that, as boost.python doesn't support Unicode strings(out out the box), and your path might have been in Unicode, arguments' conversion may fail.